# How to remove or ignore a string in python

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to ignore specific strings in python so that they don't get added to my list, for example: not including the string "front". I tried using names.remove("front") in the initial if loop, but it won't work. Any ideas how to achieve this?

```
import maya.cmds as mc
outliner = mc.ls(type='transform')
lists=[]
names=[]
for i in outliner:
    if not '|' in i:
        names.append(i)       

    if '|' in i:
        lists.append(i.split('|'))                            

for i in lists:
    names.append(i[len(i)-1]) 

projPath = mc.workspace( q=True, dir=True )+'Outliner.txt'
print(projPath)

f = open(projPath,'w')
f.write('{0:*^50}'.format('Outliner structure')+'\n')
for i in outliner:
    #print(i)
    f.write(i+'\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Naming `strings_to_ignore` a list of errr, strings to ignore ;) , you could add `if all(s not in i for s in strings_to_ignore)` condition to your if (and add '|' to the strings_to_ignore list to shorten the test).

Comment: As I see it, there's no reason to store the whole list if "|" is encountered.
With this implementation, in the list comprehension, you:
 - check if '|' is in the list's item
 - If yes, you save it, unless it is one of the "undesirable"
 - If no, you split by "|", you keep the last element and Goto 1

        outliner = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'front', 'skip|skip|delta']

        undesirable = ['front']

        names = [string  if '|' not in string else string.split('|')[-1] for \
        string in outliner if string not in undesirable

Comment: Actually the way to do it depends on whether you want to filter out strings CONTAINING undesirable patterns, or strings that EXACTLY match the undesirables.